# How to open modal with dynamically generated buttons in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button, bootstrap-modal

[Snapshot of html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUtyo.png)

As shown in the above picture user can add input fields by clicking on plus button. whenever user clicks on it additional fields will be added to the form which are generated dynamically from jquery. No i want to popup a modal for additional notes button with id ins-company-notes-1, ins-company-notes-2,ins-company-notes-3.. .Can anyone help me how to do this

**-- Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var max_fields = 5;
    var field_wrapper = $(".insurance-check-form");
    var discharge_field_wrapper = $(".discharge-insurance-form");
    var add_button = $("#add-more");
    var ins_company_count = 2;
    var dis_ins_company_count = 2;
    var adm_ins_id_count = 1;
    var dis_ins_id_count = 1;

    $(document).on("click","#add-more",(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(ins_company_count < max_fields){
            $(field_wrapper).append(' <div class="row mt-5 company-box"> <div class="col-md-3 mt-3"> <select name="insurance" class="custom-select"> <option selected>Select Insurance Company</option> <option value="icci">ICCI Prudential</option> <option value="star">Star Health Insurance</option> <option value="edelwiss">Edelwiss Tokyo</option> </select> </div><div class="col-md-2 text-center"> <div class="head4 bold">Additional notes</div> <button class="btn btn-link" id="ins-company-notes-'+ins_company_count+'" type="button"> <i class="far fa-file-alt head2 text-gray"></i></button> </div><div class="col-md-2"> <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Submit</span> <div class="material-switch pull-right"> <input id="ins-company-submit-'+ins_company_count+'" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox"/> <label for="ins-company-submit-'+ins_company_count+'" class="label-primary"></label> </div></div><div class="col-md-2"> <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Approve</span> <div class="material-switch pull-  right"> <input id="ins-company-approval-'+ins_company_count+'" name="someSwitchOption002" type="checkbox"/> <label for="ins-company-approval-'+ins_company_count+'" class="label-success"></label> </div></div><div class="col-md-2"> <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Deny</span> <div class="material-switch pull-right"> <input id="ins-company-deny-'+ins_company_count+'" name="someSwitchOption003" type="checkbox"/> <label for="ins-company-deny-'+ins_company_count+'" class="label-danger"></label> </div></div><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="fas fa-times-circle brand-color head2 mt-4 text-center"></i></a></div>');
            ins_company_count++;
        }
        else{
            alert("Sorry !! You exceeded the maximum limit.")
        }
    }))

    $(field_wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        ins_company_count--;
    });

    $("#ins-company-submit-1").change(function(){
        $(this).prop("checked") ?  $("#ins-company-approval-1").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#ins-company-deny-1").removeAttr("disabled") && $(this).attr("disabled", true) : "";
    });

    $("#ins-company-approval-1").change(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked") && $("#ins-company-deny-1").prop("checked")){
            $("#justificationmodal").modal();
            $("#ins-company-deny-1").prop("checked", false);
        };
    });

    $("#ins-company-deny-1").change(function(){
        $("#justificationmodal").modal();
        $(this).prop("checked") ? $("#ins-company-approval-1").prop("checked", false) :"";
    });

    $("#ins-company-notes-1").click(function(){
        $("#additionalnotes").modal();
    });
});
```

**-- Html**

```
<form>
    <div class="insurance-check-form">
        <div class="row mt-3 company-box">
            <div class="col-md-3 mt-3">
                <select name="insurance" class="custom-select">
                    <option selected>Custom Select Menu</option>
                    <option value="volvo">ICCI Prudential</option>
                    <option value="fiat">Blue Star</option>
                    <option value="audi">Edelwiss Tokyo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <div class="head4 bold">Additional notes</div>
                <span class="head3" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-content="Click here to add a notes">
                <button class="btn btn-link" id="ins-company-notes-1" type="button">
                <i class="far fa-file-alt head2 text-gray"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Submit</span>                                                                                                
                <div class="material-switch pull-right">                                                                                                 
                    <input id="ins-company-submit-1" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="ins-company-submit-1" class="label-primary"></label>            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Approve</span>  
                <div class="material-switch pull-right">
                    <input id="ins-company-approval-1" name="someSwitchOption002" type="checkbox" disabled/>
                    <label for="ins-company-approval-1" class="label-success"></label>            
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span class="head4 bold">Click here to Deny</span>  
                <div class="material-switch pull-right">
                    <input id="ins-company-deny-1" name="someSwitchOption003" type="checkbox" disabled/>
                    <label for="ins-company-deny-1" class="label-danger"></label>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**-- Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="additionalnotes">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title bold">Additional Notes </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">                                       
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="text" placeholder="Some text here" required></textarea>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">                 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal"  data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Done</button>                              
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please format your html snippet by clicking on edit link of your post.

Comment: Do you just only need to add the `id` in your modal? or may I miss something?

Comment: Can you refer the image attached. So when user clicks on plus button additional fields will be generated. There are three toggle buttons in the row. clicking on deny toggle button should popup a modal. I don't know how to do it for dynamically generated buttons

Answer (score 0):

Try with `document`  `on, off`

```
$(document).off('click', '#ins-company-notes-1');
$(document).on('click', '#ins-company-notes-1', function () {
   $("#additionalnotes").modal();
})
```

or

```
$(document).on("click","#add-more",(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
     if(ins_company_count < max_fields){

        }
        else{
          alert("Sorry !! You exceeded the maximum limit.")
         }/***Add Here Your Fuction***/
       $("#ins-company-notes-1").click(function(){           
          $("#additionalnotes").modal();
      })
    }))
```

Comment: Is there any another way by using variable like initializing i with 1 to 5 and looping it like   $("ins-company-notes'+i+'").click(function(){ $("#additionalnotes").modal();} )  . I tired this but not working

Comment: Thank you Lalji :). You saved my day. I have one more issue. I am using toggle buttons in the form so i am adding multiple constraints for these check boxes. So my question is how to add these constraints to dynamically generated checkbox fields. Please refer to the modified question